# Is it possible to put an image directly into a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame

I made a simple game in python using the pygame library and it worked great. The only problem is that it required images which meant that if I wanted to share my creation, I'd have to put it all in a zip (or other archive) which is a pain, especially when you're constantly updating the program.

I know this sounds a bit stupid but is there a way of encoding an image file so that it can be stored within the python file itself? For example, when opening an image in a text editor, you can see the image as text. Could I perhaps paste this into python and use some library to decode it back into an image? If not, I might just put the images on a server and make the program retrieve them each time. I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask though.

Comment: Yes, you can but there's actually no difference having the image in the source or in a file. An image is just a sequence of numbers, and all you're doing is moving that sequence from a file into another file. It will clutter your source code and make it harder to maintain.

Comment: Convert your image into Base64 and add this base64 string in your code. Convert back this string into image when needed.

Comment: Technically yes.  Instead, I would recommend that you take this as an opportunity to learn how to use packaging/freezing tools.  I usually use a setup.py file and then package everything into a wheel file, but for a game it may make more sense to use a tool like pyinstaller to make executables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and actually quite easy. You first have to decode the surface to an string using the [`pygame.image.tostring(image, format)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.tostring) function. It takes the surface and a format (probably `RGB` or `RGBA`). You can then save the returned string in your script:

```
string = pygame.image.tostring(surface, 'RGB')
print(string) # A long bytes string (b'\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff....')
```

You then load the image with [`pygame.image.fromstring(image, size, format)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring) (Where size is the expected surface size)

```
string = b'\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\x00\xff....'
surface = pygame.image.fromstring(string, surface.get_size(), 'RGB')
print(surface)
```

You just copy the output of `tostring` into the script.

Comment: Okay. Got it to work. Great! Here's a screenshot if anyone wants to see the result: https://ibb.co/dkQxRJ (Please ignore the poor-quality test image LoL). Accepted Answer :)

Comment: wow, thats a pretty clever but highly obsfucated solution, use at your own risk.